# @Valid annotation gives java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, validation

Ok. I think i gone through all possible tutorials in the internet and still can't understand why I get this error. So here it is I use NetBeans and do NOT use Maven:

libs

```
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
spring libraries (netbeans default)
hibernate libraries (netbeans default)
spring security libraries (3.0.7)
```

`spring-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="menuDao" class="lt.database.dao.MenuDao" />
<bean id="userDao" class="lt.database.dao.UserDao" />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
<!-- @Controller, @Service, @Configuration, etc. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="lt.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="lt.database.service" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->
<import resource="hibernate-config.xml" />
</beans>
```

`Controller`:

```
package lt.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import lt.database.dao.MenuDao;
import lt.database.dao.UserDao;
import lt.database.model.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private MenuDao menuDao;

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/registracija/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registracijaNew(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
        userDao.saveUser(user);
        return "redirect:/registracija";
    }
}
```

`Entity`:

```
package lt.database.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

/**
 *
 * @author Minutis
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Vartotojo vardas privalomas.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50, message = "Vartotojo vardas turi būti tarp 1 ir 50 simbolių.")
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Slaptažodis yra privalomas.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 64, message = "Slaptažodis turi būti tarp 1 ir 64 simbolių.")
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Email(message = "Netinkamai įvestas el. paštas.")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotEmpty(message = "El. paštas yra privalomas.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100, message = "El. paštas turi būti tarp 1 ir 100 simbolių.")
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "user_type")
    private byte userType;

    @Size(max = 100, message = "Vardas neturi viršyti 100 simbolių.")
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Size(max = 100, message = "Pavardė neturi viršyti 100 simbolių.")
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Size(max = 100, message = "Adresas neturi viršyti 100 simbolių.")
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Size(max = 100, message = "Telefonas neturi viršyti 100 simbolių.")
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Size(max = 100, message = "Pašto kodas neturi viršyti 100 simbolių.")
    @Column(name = "postcode")
    private String postcode;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User(Integer id, String username, String password, String email, byte userType) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] digest = md.digest();

            StringBuffer hashPassword = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
              hashPassword.append(Integer.toString((digest[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            this.password = hashPassword.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public byte getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(byte userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        }
        User other = (User) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "lt.database.model.User[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

ERROR:

```
INFO: test was successfully deployed in 17,875 milliseconds.
INFO: Hibernate: select this_.id as id28_0_, this_.link as link28_0_, this_.name as name28_0_ from aukcionas.menu this_
INFO: Hibernate: select this_.id as id28_0_, this_.link as link28_0_, this_.name as name28_0_ from aukcionas.menu this_ where this_.name=?
INFO: Hibernate: select this_.id as id28_0_, this_.link as link28_0_, this_.name as name28_0_ from aukcionas.menu this_
INFO: Hibernate: select this_.id as id28_0_, this_.link as link28_0_, this_.name as name28_0_ from aukcionas.menu this_ where this_.name=?
INFO: Hibernate: select this_.id as id28_0_, this_.link as link28_0_, this_.name as name28_0_ from aukcionas.menu this_
INFO: Hibernate: select this_.id as id28_0_, this_.link as link28_0_, this_.name as name28_0_ from aukcionas.menu this_ where this_.name=?
INFO: Hibernate: select this_.id as id28_0_, this_.link as link28_0_, this_.name as name28_0_ from aukcionas.menu this_
INFO: Hibernate: select this_.id as id28_0_, this_.link as link28_0_, this_.name as name28_0_ from aukcionas.menu this_
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[spring]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$PersistenceUtilImpl.isLoaded(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:757)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForRedefinedDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:119)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:692)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I get this error when submit empty form to url in controller. Please help, i'm gonna loose my mind...

Comment: Try leave only `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` annotations on your id field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Hibernate from 3.2.5 to 3.6.9 and Spring from 3.0.2 to 3.1.0 and the problem is solved. Did **NOT** even need to add any of these:

```
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the hibernate validator is trying to use a JPA2 method, while you only have JPA 1 on the build path.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? I have suspicion, that there might be one library related problem. NetBeans (GlassFish 3.1 to be exact) has it's own library for `javax.validator...` and my manually included `validator-api-1.0.0.jar` is not used. Maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message but not the same solution...
So for those using Netbeans and Glassfish that end up here this is for you:

- Go to your glassfish folder (c:/Program Files/...)
- In the "bin" folder there should be a "updatetool.bat", run it as administrator and wait for the script to run until the end.
- Return to the parent folder, there should be a new folder "updatetool"
- Inside "updatetool" folder there should be a "bin" folder with updatetool.exe in it, run it
- Select "Available Add-ons" and search for "Hibernate JPA", install it.

Run your project in Netbeans and it should work (restart it if it was still running and make sure, if you have multiple glassfish servers installed that you're using the right one)

I hope it helps...